# Regex Arabic Vocalization Matching

Tags: c#, regex, matching

I have the following Arabic text:

```
الْكَلَامُ عَلَيْهِ مِنْ وُجُوهٍ:أَحَدُهَا: أَنَّ هَذِهِ الْجُمْلَةَ وَنَظَائِرَهَا مِنْ خُطْبَةِ الْكِتَابِ مُرَبَّعَةٌ نُونِيَّةٌ.
```

As you can see that characters are vocalized. As far as i know, each vocal is considered as a character. At first i tried the below options in online regex testing websites and they both worked and returned results but in C# it never did work. I tried the following:

```
        var t1 = Regex.Matches(txt, "/[ًٍَِْ]/g", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
        var t2 = Regex.Matches(txt, "/([\u064B-\u0652])/g", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

In t1, i tried to match the vocals themselves (َ ِ ُ ْ ٍ ّ) but that didn't work as it gives zero matches. In t2, i tried using their Unicode representation and it didn't work also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using

```
var inp1 = "الْكَلَامُ عَلَيْهِ مِنْ وُجُوهٍ:أَحَدُهَا: أَنَّ هَذِهِ الْجُمْلَةَ وَنَظَائِرَهَا مِنْ خُطْبَةِ الْكِتَابِ مُرَبَّعَةٌ نُونِيَّةٌ.";
var t2 = Regex.Matches(inp1, "[\u064B-\u0652]", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

You are using JavaScript notation in the C# pattern that prevents from matching.

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: I cannot copy `t1` correctly in my VS2012 :( It appears as some jibberish... And captured group count is smaller (just 42 occurrences). I'd go with the hexadecimals. Did you consider using `\p{IsArabic}`?

Comment: @stribizhev There are 8 characters in the unicode range `[\u064B-\u0652]`, while only 5 in the explicit regex. If you do a `(?![ًٍَِْ])[\u064B-\u0652]` you'll see that there are exactly 13 characters that are excluded by the specific range and included in the unicode range (55-42 = 13)

Comment: If i am to use IsArabic, it would mean all arabic characters. I just want to match specific ones.

Comment: I see, I just thought you could subtract what you do not want from the `\p{IsArabic}`. I am not an expert in the language.

Comment: the gibberish part is  َ ً  ِ  ٍ ْ ُ  ٌ  ّ      ,  \u064B \u0650 \u064D \u0652 \u064F \u064C \u0651